# Should I initialize object values?

Tags: java

The question may sound a bit silly, but should an object class look something like this:

```
class Book {
  String title;
  int year;
  ///so on and so forward 
 }
```

or should it look like this?

```
class Book {
  String title = "";
  int year = 0;
  ///so on and so forward 
 }
```

i understand that actual values should be set by the constructor (or setValue methods), but should the initial values be null, or 0/"" ?

Edit: Im trying to work with the object values as strings (replacing certain characters, etc), which doesnt work if the value is null; i wasnt sure if i should add an "if" clause or simply initialize values to an empty string

Comment: you can but that is the work of the constructor.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
public class Book {
private String title;
private int year;
} 

public Book(String titleIn, int yearIn) {
    title = titleIn;
    year = yearIn;
}
```

And the way you should create the object is:

```
Book harryPotter = new Book("Harry Potter", 2014);
```